# Uptime iOS Objective-C - millisecond precision

Tags: ios, objective-c, uptime

I'm trying to get uptime for iOS. I was using mach_absolute_time - but I found that it paused during sleep.

I found this snippet:

```
- (time_t)uptime
{
    struct timeval boottime;
    int mib[2] = {CTL_KERN, KERN_BOOTTIME};
    size_t size = sizeof(boottime);
    time_t now;
    time_t uptime = -1;

    (void)time(&now);

    if (sysctl(mib, 2, &boottime, &size, NULL, 0) != -1 && boottime.tv_sec != 0)
    {
        uptime = now - boottime.tv_sec;
    }
    return uptime;
}
```

It does the trick. BUT, it's returning whole seconds. Any way to get milliseconds out of this?

Comment: I am not sure but NSTimeInterval give you in ms `NSTimeInterval timePassed_ms = [date timeIntervalSinceNow] * -1000.0;` and check `NSDate* bootDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:
                               boottime.tv_sec + boottime.tv_usec / 1.e6];`

Comment: Getting weird values: 1330475899251.326172
2013-04-14 01:08:54.996 app[1486:c07] 1365915981675.174072
2013-04-14 01:08:54.997 app[1486:c07] 1330475899257.684082
2013-04-14 01:08:55.012 app[1486:c07] 1365915981691.614258

Comment: that is not weired that in number of seconds elapsed since 1970.... :)

Comment: But the numbers are changing kinda random actually :P

Comment: how can time be same? time always change :)

Comment: Haha, yes, I know. BUT the numbers are repeating back and forth.

Comment: Like : 07] 1365916351.173829
2013-04-14 01:15:04.581 app[1539:c07] 1330476268.841522
2013-04-14 01:15:04.582 app[1539:c07] 1365916351.176842
2013-04-14 01:15:04.584 app[1539:c07] 1330476268.844556
2013-04-14 01:15:04.585 app[1539:c07] 1365916351.182255

Answer (score 3):

If you want something pure Objective-C, try

```
NSTimeInterval uptime = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] systemUptime];
```

(`NSTimeInterval` is a typedef for `double`, representing seconds.)

Comment: Will this pause when the iDevice is sleeping?

Answer (score 3):

The kernel does not (apparently) store a higher-resolution timestamp of its boot time.

`KERN_BOOTTIME` is implemented by [the `sysctl_boottime` function in `bsd/kern/kern_sysctl.c`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1699.32.7/bsd/kern/kern_sysctl.c).  It calls `boottime_sec`.

`boottime_sec` is implemented in [`bsd/kern/kern_time.c`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1699.32.7/bsd/kern/kern_time.c).  It calls `clock_get_boottime_nanotime`, which has a promising name.

`clock_get_boottime_nanotime` is implemented in [`osfmk/kern/clock.c`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1699.32.7/osfmk/kern/clock.c).  It is hard-coded to always return 0 in its `nanosecs` argument.

Comment: Any other methods that can achieve what I need?

Comment: It's not clear what you really need.  Why do you need millisecond precision for a duration that is likely to be hours or days long?

Comment: It's a long story. But I do need it :)

Comment: @objectiveccoder001 Have you got the solution? I am searching for that for a long time, too...

Answer (score 2):

I know it's probably too late, but there you go:

```
+ (NSTimeInterval)uptime {
    struct timeval boottime;
    int mib[2] = {CTL_KERN, KERN_BOOTTIME};
    size_t size = sizeof(boottime);

    struct timeval now;
    struct timezone tz;
    gettimeofday(&now, &tz);

    double uptime = -1;

    if (sysctl(mib, 2, &boottime, &size, NULL, 0) != -1 && boottime.tv_sec != 0) {
        uptime = now.tv_sec - boottime.tv_sec;
        uptime += (double)(now.tv_usec - boottime.tv_usec) / 1000000.0;
    }
    return uptime;
}
```

Comment: Does anyone have a Swift implementation of Victor's answer?