# QueryPerformanceCounter(), but on OSX

Tags: c++, c, time, timer, performancecounter

This question has been asked before (see [What's the equivalent of Windows' QueryPerformanceCounter on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464618/whats-the-equivalent-of-windows-queryperformancecounter-on-osx)), but it seems like my needs are a bit different than in other questions, so I'm going to ask again.

All I'm looking for is a tick counter - I don't need UTC or anything like that. And I need a timer that isn't affected by sleep-mode - I need a tick counter that accurately reflects how many ticks have passed, even while the machine was in sleep mode.

`QueryPerformanceCounter()` on win32 has a number of nice properties that fit my requirements:

- High resolution, down to microseconds
- Continues counting, even in system sleep (or rather its count includes time that went by when the system was in sleep mode)
- Monotonic - never goes down. Not affected by changing the system time.

On OSX, as far as I can tell, I have the following alternatives, and none of them are very good:

1. `gettimeofday()`

   - resolution is down to milliseconds (ok, not great)
   - continues counting in system sleep (good)
   - is affected by changing the system clock (bad)
2. `mach_absolute_time()`

   - resolution is down to microseconds (good)
   - doesn't count in system sleep (bad)
   - not affected by changing system clock (good)
3. `host_get_clock_service( SYSTEM_CLOCK )` & `clock_get_time()` (see mach/clock.h)

   - seems to be identical to `mach_absolute_time()`
4. `host_get_clock_service( CALENDAR_CLOCK )` & `clock_get_time()` (see mach/clock.h)

   - seems to be identical to `gettimeofday()`

I don't think that I fully appreciated just how great `QueryPerformanceCounter()` was until I started looking at this problem. How does it work? Does it use the HPET? Does the HPET go to sleep when the system goes to sleep? If not, why doesn't OSX expose the HPET this way? If so, how does Windows compensate for this?

Update 1:

There's an interesting discussion of how `QueryPerformanceCounter` works here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx

Apparently it once used CPU TSCs in Win XP days, switched to using the HPET/ACPI timers in Vista, and switched again to improved TSCs in Win 7 but falling back to HPET/ACPI. Still, I was always under the impression that the HPET and TSC didn't survive sleep mode.

Comment: Use `std::chrono`. It's cross-platform.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12490414/65863

Comment: @RemyLebeau: sysctl(KERN_BOOTTIME) returns boot time in seconds. It can't be used as part of a high resolution monotonic counter. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995995/uptime-ios-objective-c-millisecond-precision.

Comment: @Rapptz: Sadly, I'm not using C++11. Any idea which timer std::chrono uses on OSX?

Comment: @Rapptz: It appears that std::chrono is just using gettimeofday() and mach_absolute_time(). See http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/src/chrono.cpp.

Comment: @TedMiddleton I'm not sure about the implementation but I know libc++ is typically standard conforming and a `<chrono>` implementation is supposed to meet all the requirements you've put forth.

Comment: @Rapptz: Just tried std::chrono::steady_clock and std::chrono::high_resolution_clock. Both behave identically to mach_absolute_time(). Which makes sense given that that's how they're implemented. Either the C++11 spec doesn't stipulate sleep behavior for std::chrono, or std::chrono on OSX is out of spec.

Comment: @TedMiddleton Well, this works: http://ideone.com/d6iFcW on Linux and Windows. Might be out of spec on Mac OS X.